# Xerox printer scales down all prints

Tags: printer, scaling

With the international firm I'm working for, we have a Xeros ColorQube 9303 in the office in the US. This printer has been fitted with four trays and a manual feeding bin. For the sake of this issue, we loaded all trays with 'letter' paper. There is no print server and we are printing directly to the machine.

When printing any type of document, with all the 'normal' settings on the computers, the documents get scaled down. This itself is not a big issue if we print single paged documents, but if we print more pages, each following page also moves up a bit. After a couple of pages, this means that content of the top of one page, is being printed on the bottom of the previous page.

We had multiple engineers and an analyst of Xeros checking out the printer, our settings, the drivers, and even the machines software itself. All checks out normally according to them, and they were able to reproduce the issue on our systems. However, when they print on their own laptops the printing is done correctly.

<s>The last analyst that was on-site did find a work-around for us, but of course we are looking for a permanent solution. The work-around is to print the required document with a PDF printer, and then re-print the document to the Xerox machine with the option *"Choose paper source by PDF size"* enabled. Only in this way, the printer doesn't scale down the print.</s>

Installing different drivers does not change the behavior. We tried multiple types of drivers:

- Generic, Manufacturer-Generic, and printer specific
- PCL and PS
- Old and new (even beta)

Why does this behavior occur, and more importantly: Does anyone have a permanent fix so we can also correctly print documents from other applications such as Word and Excel?

PS: Could someone add the tags 'Xerox' and/or 'ColorCube'? I'm short just a bit of reputation on this site.

***) Update:** We received a message from our US office that the work-around does not work either.

Comment: This sounds like a driver rather than a printer problem. Many applications (Word, Excel, etc) show a print preview. How does that look? Try installing a local driver on a laptop, bypassing the server (create a Standard TCP/IP port to talk to the printer). If that prints correctly, compare ALL driver settings with those of a PC that has the problem.

Comment: The print previews all look fine, and the pages are all on their on sheet of virtual paper.. As explained, we currently do NOT have a print server in between, and are using a direct standard TCP/IP port to the printer. We did do a full compare of the settings of the domain joined PCs with the issues, and the non-domain joined laptop without the issue, but all checks out.

Comment: Do you have this problem with different programs or just with one?

Comment: Just to rule out the printer completely, have you tried to reset it to factory defaults (a Software Reset)? See http://wss.support.xerox.com/GTConnect/UnifiedAcceptor/AddWebFramework.Main/site/XeroxProductSupport/product/product_cq930x/lang/en-US/region/region_US/source/DND/Xlang/en_US/Xcntry/USA/prodID/CQ930X/KBlang/en//t/1479810213269#!view-content/ViewContent/View/contentId/x_cq_en-O2914

Comment: @ Seth this happens with all applications, even Word, Excel etc..  
@ hdhondt we tried it, but unfortunately it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: If this was happening within the printer, page shrinkage couldn't pull content from subsequent pages because there is a page eject after each page.  The problem is almost certainly in settings in the applications software or driver software.  The problem happening only from your computers and not from the service techs' laptops confirms that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that one of the Office plugins that generates a footer for our documents, even though disabled, causes the prints to be scaled down. We are not sure how this is possible, but by uninstalling the plugin entirely, we "fixed" the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i've had the same bug with a WC5845, on all drivers (PS, PCL ...) 
so, in desperation, i've changed the driver to the one for WC5875 :) 
and it works alright now. (on win7x64). 
so, a mismatching driver works better; i've seen this before.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for us..